# Redirect www or without www using NGINX to run Node JS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ubuntu, nginx

I used

```
nano /etc/nginx/conf.d/domain.com.conf

---- Copy and Paste ------------------

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name domain.com;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    location / {
        proxy_pass "http://localhost:3000/";
    }
}
```

What thing I need to add then [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) will work properly or redirect to domain.com
Please advise me

Should I try ServerAlias?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to make use of both www. and non www you can simply edit the server name to be the following.

```
server_name example.com www.example.com
```

However, if you wish to redirect www. to non www you can use such an if statement:

```
if ($host = www.example.com) {
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

However, there is this discussion that if statement are not preferred in nginx, not quite sure on the validity of that so here is another possible solution:

This approach redirects all `www` requests to `non-www`

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name www.example.com;
        return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: It's not working. Can you please help more?

Comment: Could you please provide more information, is there any sort of error? Did you restart nginx after applying these changes?

Comment: nano /etc/nginx/conf.d/example.com.conf
<br />
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name example.com;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
location / {
proxy_pass "http://localhost:3000/";
}
}

How to work www or without www?

Comment: Your issue is that you are missing the `www.example.com` in your `server_name` field. Change it to `server_name example.com www.example.com;` and you should be set.

Comment: it's working but i added cname with cloudflare.

Comment: Great @eRevolute, please mark answer as valid.